# Converting MP3 to Video - Use image of Metadata text as Video track?

Tags: video, youtube, mp3

I have many MP3 files which are recordings of music concerts . each of them have Meta data for

eg :  (using ffprobe)

```
Metadata:
    title           : Vishweshwara
    genre           : Flute
    album           : Sindu Bhairavi
    artist          : Sikkil Sisters
 Duration: 00:06:23.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
```

Now I want to convert these mp3 into mp4 for uploading to Youtube. 
I am aware that I can use :

```
for i in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -v quiet -i "picture.jpg" -i "$i" -shortest -acodec copy "`sed 's/mp3/mp4/g'<<<$i`"; done
```

But for the `"picture.jpg"` part I want a picture generated from the metadata text of that file. In short: All I want is the above shown metadata text on a white background exported to use later as `picture.jpg` when generating a video in FFmpeg.

How can I do that for all the mp3 files that i have inside a folder using a script?

I tried the following script that i cooked up but the video output contains no data (not even the original audio nor the new image)

```
for i in *.mp3; 
do 

convert label:"$(mediainfo "$i")" picture.jpg

ffmpeg -v quiet -i "picture.jpg" -i "$i" -shortest -acodec copy "`sed 's/mp3/mp4/g'<<<$i`";

rm picture.jpg


done
```

can some one help me why these videos are not being generated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after doing a lot of research i came up with a messy solution . Im posting it here so that someone searching for the would be benefited.

```
#!/bin/bash

###this script needs  "mediainfo" get it with
#sudo apt-get install mediainfo 
#if you dont have it
######Made by Ashwin 

mkdir output;

for i in *.mp3; 
do 
f="${i[@]/%mp3/mp4}"

convert label:"$(mediainfo "$i")" ""$i".png";

ffmpeg -v quiet -loop 1 -r 1 -i ""$i".png" -i "$i" -c:a copy -shortest "$f";
rm ""$i".png";
mv "$f" output/"$f";

done
```

save it as `scr.sh` and run `chmod 755 scr.sh` in the terminal . copy it to the location where your songs are kept then run `./scr.sh`